# Parenteses rectos (colchetes) errados?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Tenho esta função no Matlab

```
cn = reshape(repmat(sn, n_rep, 1), 1,[]);
```

no Python tenho o seguinte código:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint

M=2
N=2*10**8 ### valor de Dados
n_rep = 3 ## numero de repetições
sn = randint(0,M,size = N)### Inteiros 0 e 1
print("sn=", sn)
cn_repmat=np.tile(sn,n_rep)
print("cn_repmat=", cn_repmat)
cn=np.reshape(cn_repmat,1,[])
print(cn)
```

não tenho a certeza se os parenteses rectos no python são assim pois dá-me o seguinte erro

```
  File "C:/Users/Sergio Malhao/.spyder-py3/Desktop/untitled6.py", line 17, in <module>
    cn=np.reshape(cn_repmat,1,[])

  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 232, in reshape
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)

  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 57, in _wrapfunc
    return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 600000000 into shape (1,)
```

Comment: Esse erro não sobre `Parênteses`, erro de *Parênteses* é assim `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses`

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza o *parentesis recto* é o que chamamos de colchete. Possivelmente o autor é de outro país. Acredito que a dúvida está se é certo utilizar `[]` na função `reshape`.

Comment: sim a duvida é se está certo usar colchetes(parentesis) e como poderei fazer a sintaxe correcta, no cn

Answer (score 1):

O problema é de sintaxe. Você copiou o código sem olhar o que a funcão do python usa como entrada.

Com uma olhada no [manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) é possível ver que a uma cópia direta matlab->python não funciona.

O erro:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 600000000 into shape (1,)

é exatamente pois o formato que foi dado como entrada não é aceito.

O que você deve usar é

```
cn=np.reshape(cn_repmat,(Linhas,Colunas))
```

No seu caso, como a intencão é ter apenas uma linha, a entrada `-1` para o valor das colunas é o ideal. Esta entrada nesta funcão tem o mesmo efeito do `[]` do matlab, ficando assim:

```
cn=np.reshape(cn_repmat,(1,-1))
```

Porém, esta funcão não me parece necessária dado o seu código. Pois o `tile` está apenas copiando uma matriz de uma linha `sn` `n_rep` vezes na mesma linha.

### Olhando os dados

Olhando a entrada/saida de dados da expressão inicial temos:

```
a=1:4
reshape(repmat(a, 4, 1), 1,[])
ans =
[ 1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4 ]
```

em python

```
b=np.array([1,2,3,4])
np.reshape(np.tile(b,(4,1)),(1,-1))
>array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Logo, isto não funciona. Porém, basta apenas usar a matriz transposta `cn_repmat.T` que ela fica na mesma ordem do matlab.

```
np.reshape(np.tile(b,(4,1)).T,(1,-1))
>array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]])
```

Uma outra opcão é também usar [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), que faz exatamente como você quer a ainda tem a opcão *FORTRAN* `(order='F')` que lê a matriz *column-wise* :

```
np.tile(b,(4,1)).ravel(order='F')
>array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4])
```

Comment: E quais modificações são essas?

Comment: Guto então ficaria cn=np.reshape(1,cn_repmat)? ando de volta disto há 3 horas, pode-me ajudar?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Está aí :D !

Comment: Ótima resposta!

Comment: @SergioNunes, cá está a resposta.